# iframe problems

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page that has an embedded iframe doing ajax requests....
when i click on a link i want the new link to open up in the main window and not the iframe which it is doing right now...
i tried doing this in javascript

window.parent.location.href = url of link

doesnt work...
anyone out there with a better idea to do this???

also i need popups to appear onhover over the links...right now they get clipped by the main page....

thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `target="_parent"` to the anchors.

But judging from your requirements, I'm suspecting an iframe is not the ideal solution for you at all. You might want to consider switching do a div with fixed width and height and an `overflow: auto` style.

Comment: david,
i am using the salesforce api components to render controls on the page...the controls inherently are rendering an iframe in html...i already tried to set the target to the parent but that did not work either..

Comment: :D slip of the tongue, er, keyboard... fingers? whatever. `overflow: auto` of course

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
top.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```